# Adding image from Firebase to UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to retrieve the image that is stored in the storage of an user and place it next to his name in a custom UITableViewCell. The problem now is that the tableview will load when the images aren't done downloading (I think?), causing the application to crash because the image array is nil. So what is the correct way to load the tableview? I think, for the user experience, it is important that the tableviewcell image should be shown even if the images aren't done downloading, and present them a default image that is saved in the assists. I thought about making an array with UIImages that links to the default asset of loading an image and changing the image to the profile picture when it is done downloading. But I really have no clue how to do that. This is what I got so far about downloading the image:

```
let storage = FIRStorage.storage()
        let storageRef = storage.reference(forURL: "link.appspot.com")
        channelRef?.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let snapDict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
                for each in snapDict{
                    let UIDs = each.value["userID"] as? String
                    if let allUIDS = UIDs{
                        let profilePicRef = storageRef.child((allUIDS)+"/profile_picture.png")
                        profilePicRef.data(withMaxSize: 1 * 500 * 500) { data, error in
                            if let error = error {
                            }
                            if (data != nil)
                            {
                                self.playerImages.append(UIImage (data: data!)!)
                            }
                        }

                    }
let userNames = each.value["username"] as? String
                    if let users = userNames{
                        self.players.append(users)
                    }
                }
        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
```

This is in the cellForRow

```
cell.playersImage.image = playerImages[indexPath.row] as UIImage
```

My rules, haven't changed it from the default rules:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/omega-towers-f5beb.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `tableView.reloadData()` when the images are done downloading. One important thing, initialize your playerImages as `playerImages = [UIImage]()` instead of `playerImages: [UIImage]!`. if it's empty, it wouldn't show your array is nil.

Update:

```
if let players = playerImages {
   //code
}
```

Comment: Im sorry I did not include that in my code. I already initialized playerImages as you do aswell . The problem is that the table will load when the view appears, it will not wait for the images to have loaded. But then again, what I want is to check if the array contains a image, if not, presenting a normal image that is saved in the assets. I can not use the if playerImages != nil in the cellForRow.

Comment: I have edited my answer. You can check for nil just by using if let statement. if it's nil, it won't go inside if statement. One more thing, if your array is initialized and empty, your numberofrowsinSection should return 0, and cellforrowat IndexPath won't give you an error.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding user experience, you are correct. It is standard to have some sort of default image when loading an image from a URL. A great library to use for image caching and using default assets in its' place is [AlamofireImage](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage)

Vandan Patel's answer is correct in saying you need to ensure your array is not nil when loading the tableview. You will be given a completion block to handle any extra work you would like to do with your image, using the AlamofireImage library.

This is all assuming you are getting a correct image URL back for your Firebase users.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I see some good functions about AlamofireImage, but I am concerned about answering my question. I think my code is not correct, so adding Alamo to my project would not fix my code.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's hard to extrapolate exactly what your question is. So if you could elaborate a little more concisely, then maybe I can assist. I thought your original question was how to use a placeholder image in place of a loading image.